# How to change the timezone in Python Tweepy Library

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-3.x, tweepy

So far, I like Tweepy, the Python library for working with the Twitter API; however, does anyone know how to change the timezone in the datetime data that is returns?

```
search = api.search(
    q='#some_hashtag',
    count=100,
)
```

The above code is what I am using to query twitter search api for a certain hashtag. The results are stored into a database table. This is all happening in a Django Rest API application.

Is there a setting in Tweepy or a Django ORM work around, an aggregate, that can adjust the timezone to be accurate. The timezone seems to be 5 hours off.

Comment: What is the string returned by the API?

Comment: Tweepy does some magic and turns that string into python, so each javascript object the api returns, Tweepy converts it into a python object. The datetime field returned becomes a python datetime object.